# Show recent modified/created files using Terminal

Tags: command-line, files, gnome-terminal

Is there any command to display the recently modified/created files?

Which one...?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
find ${1} -type f | xargs stat --format '%Y :%y %n' 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2-
```

See [Find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) command

<sup>[Source:Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566310/how-to-recursively-find-and-list-the-latest-modified-files-in-a-directory-with-s)</sup>

Comment: The command is correct.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah,it's correct,it just takes some time.I thought -f2- would be incorrect because commands don't generally end with an -

Comment: Nice one! What about ignoring hidden files?

Comment: You can use `-iname`.  For example, find *.txt file but ignore hidden .txt file such as .vimrc you would `-type f \( -iname "*.txt" ! -iname ".*" \)`.

Comment: @Mitch how to specify to find files in last 2 days?

Comment: You can use `find -type f -atime +2`.  For more info see [manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

Answer (score 14):

Check `stat` command:

Usage:

```
stat [options] filename ... ...
```

e.g.

```
stat /home/user/Docs/filename.txt
```

To search for files, use `find` commands:

e.g.

```
find /to/target/directory* -mtime -1
```

(the switch `-mtime n` show file's with data last modified n*24 hours ago, for `-mtime -1` the files 1 day old will be shown)

```
find /to/target/directory* -mmin 30
```

will show files modified in last 30 minutes.

Check for more options under TESTS in the manual pages (use `man find` in terminal). You can use other switches like `-amin n` (last accessed n minutes ago), `-cmin` (file's status was last changed n minutes ago), and others.

Comment: Maybe you could consider either removing the stat part from your answer or giving a specific command.

Comment: `stat filename` where filename could be your target's absolute or relative path. This will show access, modification, change times among other outputs..

Comment: `stat` will also give you the file's _birth_ time if the filesystem supports that..

Comment: The asker wants to see a list of recently changed files.`stat` gives out properties of a specific file or directory(like when it was modified last time). Therefore this command is not appropriate for this question.

Comment: ..it's related, isn't it? It shows you the time stamps.. and what OP want's is a practical implementation of the same..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12688/discussion-between-aditya-patil-and-hash)

Comment: is there a need? check [Mitch's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/411468/212123).. it uses `stat` for the search (if need an example)..

Answer (score 5):

```
ls -t
```

This will sort the list of files by modification time