# How do i find the recently used files through terminal?

Tags: command-line

I want to see the recently used(accessed) files along with their path through terminal.

How could i get that files list?

**Note:** This question is not a duplicate of [Show recent modified/created files using Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411462/show-recent-modified-created-files-using-terminal)

Comment: Hey , so you mean like only the files used through terminal ?

Comment: @raaz no, just view a file through nautilus and then run the command on my answer. It will display the recently accessed files along with it's path.

Answer (score 6):

It works on Ubuntu systems which has `nautilus` as a default file-manager.

Run the below command on terminal to see the recently accessed(aka viewed) files.

```
sed -nr 's/.*href="([^"]*)".*/\1/p' ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

Information about all the recently accessed files are stored in this particular `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` file. Extracting only the file along with it's path was done by the above command.

**Command Explanation:**

```
sed -nr 's/.*href="([^"]*)".*/\1/p' ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

`-n`   --> suppress automatic printing of pattern space

`-r`   --> Extended regex. If we use sed with `-r`, then we don't have to escape some characters like (`(`,`)`,`{`,`}`,etc)

`'s/.*href="([^"]*)".*/\1/p'` --> sed searches for a line which has this(`.*href="([^"]*)".*`) regex in the input file. If it find any, then it grabs only the characters that are within double quotes which was after `href=`(`href=""`) and stored it in a group. Only the stored group are printed through back-reference(`\1`).

**Example:**

```
$ sed -nr 's/.*href="([^"]*)".*/\1/p' ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
file:///media/truecrypt8/bar.txt
file:///media/truecrypt8/picture.txt
file:///media/truecrypt8/bob.txt
file:///media/truecrypt8/movie.txt
file:///media/truecrypt8/music.txt
file:///media/truecrypt8/foo.txt
```

If you want the output to be formatted then run this,

```
$ sed -nr 's/.*href="([^"]*)".*/\1/p' ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel | sed 's|\/\/| |g'
file: /media/truecrypt8/bar.txt
file: /media/truecrypt8/picture.txt
file: /media/truecrypt8/bob.txt
file: /media/truecrypt8/movie.txt
file: /media/truecrypt8/music.txt
file: /media/truecrypt8/foo.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain you command so we can understand ?

Comment: this commands only works on Ubuntu ?

Comment: @raaz It works on Ubuntu but i don't know about others.

Comment: Ok Friend, +1 for great work. Nice explanation indeed.