# where is recent directory

Tags: nautilus, directory

I suddenly open recent directory. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to see, what is its path directory. and I saw `recent:///` is that a path? So where is recent directory?

Update:

or better to say:

In terminal if I want to `cd` recent directory. what do I should inter ?

Comment: similar http://askubuntu.com/a/470091/202806

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's a Nautilus-specific fake path, similar to the `about:` protocol in Firefox and `chrome:` in Chrom{e,ium}.

If you want a command line history (to see where you've been recently on the command line) you can run `history | grep cd` but this is specific to your shell (`zsh` and `bash` should work) and it won't factor in your recent directories.

Recent files (not directories) are stored in `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` by a number of desktop applications (including Nautilus) so if you just need a list of those, you can extract them with:

```
awk -F '[ |"]' '/<bookmark / {print $5}'  ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

Comment: Is stored a copy of original file in recent directory or just a link of original file? thank you.